# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.ALL_APPS }

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, startactivityforresult

I want to use two Intent in same class, but it is not showing no Activity found to handle the intent. It is showing error in `activityforesult` method in `Updf setOnClickListener`.

This is my Class

```
public class Electronic extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button Updf , Uimage;
private EditText Title , Description ;
private  StorageReference storageReference;
private static final int GINT = 1 , pINT = 2;
private ProgressDialog bar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_electronic);

    Updf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Updf);
    Uimage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Uimage);
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    Updf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent pdfintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS );

            startActivityForResult(pdfintent , pINT);
        }
    });
    Uimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(intent, GINT);
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Uri uri;
    StorageReference refchild;
    Log.v("REquest code" , String.valueOf(requestCode));
    switch (requestCode)
        {
            case pINT :
                if(resultCode != RESULT_OK)
                    return;
                if (data.getData() == null ) {
                    return;
                }
                uri = data.getData();
                refchild = storageReference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()).child("Document").child(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                refchild.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        bar.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(Electronic.this,"Document Uploaded" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                break;
            case GINT:
                if(resultCode != RESULT_OK)
                    return;
                if(data.getData() == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                bar.show();
                uri = data.getData();
                refchild = storageReference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()).child("Images").child(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                refchild.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        bar.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(Electronic.this,"Image Uploaded" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                break;
        }



}
 }
```

And the error Occurring is

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.ALL_APPS }
>                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1809)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
>                                                                                      at com.example.him.collegeapp.Electronic$1.onClick(Electronic.java:48)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Apparently, your device does not have an activity set to handle `android.intent.action.ALL_APPS`. What device are you trying this on? Also, note that `ACTION_ALL_APPS` uses `startActivity()`, not `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: I want to upload pdf file to my firebase storage so, for that which intent should be used ? @CommonsWare   I am running this app on android emulator

Comment: `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, with a MIME type of `application/pdf`. Or, on Android 4.4+, use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, also with a MIME type of `application/pdf`.

Comment: Should i use 'startActivityForResult()' or startActivity().. @CommonsWare

Comment: `startActivityForResult()`. You will get a `Uri` as you do with `ACTION_PICK`.

Comment: Thanxxx now its working.... @CommonsWare